# How to setup clef signer with clef --stdio-ui

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I have geth running on rinkeby network and successfully used clef as a signer using command.

clef --keystore ~/.ethereum/rinkeby/keystore --chainid 4 --stdio-ui

Also started geth with clef as signer using :

geth --rinkeby --rpc --syncmode "light" --rpcport 8543 --rpcaddr 192.168.0.120 --rpccorsdomain "*" --port "35555" --rpcapi "eth,net,web3,personal,miner,admin" --signer=/home/ayanworks/.clef/clef.ipc

Then I connected geth with rpc using

geth attach rpc:http://192.168.0.120:8543 and hit eth.accounts

After that, on clef terminal, I get the following output.

In this scenario, I am not getting prompt to approve request for y/n on clef terminal.

Please update if I am following the wrong setup steps

[image: clef --stdio-ui output for approving account list]

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the --stdio-ui parameter, you have to interact in json format.
For example to reply with your password phrase use:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":{"text": "password phrase"}}
```

When experimenting it is easier to start without the --stdio-ui parameter, then you can just paste the password and enter anwers like "y".